# How to control new window in nightwatchjs

Tags: nightwatch.js

Am using nightwatchjs to automate submission of a support form. Clicking a link using nightwatchjs opens the form page in a new window. How can I set focus on that window?  Any help is  greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could also try navigating directly to the URL of the support form? If what you need to test is the submission of said form, as opposed to what happens when you click the support form button (this doesn't answer the OP but it might help).

Answer (score 6):

Use the switchWindow command.
https://nightwatchjs.org/api/switchWindow.html

Comment: Link doesn't apply any more

Answer (score 4):

I try to give you a more detailed explanation with examples of code. Currently I use `chromedriver 2.43.1` (installed with npm), `selenim standalone 3.141.5` and `nigtwatch 0.9.21`.

```
module.exports = {
    'Test new tab open': function (browser) {
        browser.url('http://localhost:8000')
            .click('#a-href-with-target-blank')
        // Switch to new tab
        browser.window_handles(function (result) {
            // 0 == current main window, 1 == new tab
            var handle = result.value[1];
            browser.switchWindow(handle);
        });
        // do something
        browser.closeWindow(); // Close tab
        // Switch to main window
        browser.window_handles(function (result) {
            // 0 == current main window, 1 == new tab
            var handle = result.value[0];
            browser.switchWindow(handle);
        });
    }
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is 'windowsHandles()" now: https://nightwatchjs.org/api/switchWindow.html#apimethod-page